# Using KMM project as module in Android project

Tags: android, module, kotlin-multiplatform, multiplatform

So I have a KMM project which has common code for iOS and Android and also native code for each platform. This project is supposed to be integrated as a module for each platform into a main app. I'm developing the Android main app, so I'm asking if this can be done and how. I've tried to add the KMM project as a module into the main Android app but I get a lot of errors regarding libraries used in the KMM module.

Comment: Can you share your gradle setup? You should be able to add the KMM module to your Android app using `implementation(project(":your_kmm_module"))`. Also could you share some of the errors?

Comment: you can [create](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-mobile-create-first-app.html) an empty KMM iOS+Android project and compare your setup with it